# Omiting --always-strict from 'tsconfig.json' in an ESM module

Tags: typescript, configuration, es6-modules

##### ESM & `"use strict"`

---

Since the release of the following `tsconfig.json` flags...

- ###### `$ tsc --module "Node16"`
- ###### `$ tsc --moduleResolution "Node16"`

...I have been writing only ES6-Standardized JavaScript
Modules, in **"TypeScript"**. It is my understanding that
adding "use strict"; to a JavaScript document, is like
adding a parsing directive to the document (it might even
be a parsing directive, I don't really know). The unique
statement informs the JavaScript engine *(when the*
*JS-engine interprets the statement)* that certain rules
are to be enforced.

**The "use strict" rules include, but are not limited
to...**

- `arguments.callee` is not allowed
- The `with` keyword is not allowed
- An object's keys must be unique
- *and a some others that I can't recall rn...*

2B Frank, the specifics of `"use strict"`, are not all
that important in the context of this question. What
really matters, is my understanding of how the use-strict
rules are implemented in ES-Modules. From what I gather,
they are part of the ESM-standard's specification, and
therefore, there is no reason that `"use strict";` needs
to be added to files in an ES-Module.

##### The TSC `--alwaysStrict` Flag

---

According to the [TypeScriptLang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#alwaysStrict) Docs the `tsc` flag,
**`"alwaysStrict": true`**, ensures that that files are each
emitted with `"use strict";` at the top of them. Considering
that ESM implements the "use strict" rules, without the need
for the `"use strict";` statement added to the file, shouldn't
it be safe to simply stop adding `"alwaysStrict": true` to
`tsconfig.json` files that are in ESM projects?

Originally I asked because there were a few Repositories I followed on GitLab & GitHub, and I noticed non had omitted "alwaysStrict". They all still included it. Then another aspect was made clear to me in the comments, after the original version of this question was authored (since then I have edited the question for spelling & grammar mistakes, as well as run-on sentences, and incorrect nomenclature (which I fixed).

So, in a nutshell, what I want to do is remove "alwaysStrict" if I can do it without risk of negative consequences. I mean, if it's useless, why have it? So I would like to know either how I can know that I can safely remove it, or just what the possible implications are for removing it. Is it just a waste of space, or is there circumstances in which I may still want "alwaysStrict" in my `tsconfig.json` file, &/or `"use strict"` in my emitted JavaScript project-build files.

Comment: Are you actually generating ESM files? Check out target directory. That's ultimately what matters for the run-time checks `use strict` offers.

Comment: @Evert, wow, so no its not emitting as ESM. Wow, great call. I am really glad I asked this question. So had I omitted it, it would have been a mistake to do so, considering that I want `"use strict";` enforced.

Comment: Yea, I found that it is still emitting `require` to import libraries & modules. I obviously have a lot more reading to do. That is crazy. What does one add, or not add, to their `tsonfig.json` file to ensure ESM is emitted?

Comment: Read the docs and open a new question here if you get stuck!

Comment: @jD3V https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module

Comment: TY sir @Bergi. I really love you n TJ. What a great resource to be able to pin point me to.